# Profiling Javascript in PyV8

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, v8, pyv8

I have a JS codebase running within PyV8. Now I'd like to improve its performance, but there don't seem to be any hooks to enable the V8 profiler. In [an older trunk version of PyV8](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/source/browse/trunk/setup.py?r=422) there are some options referencing the profiler but I don't find any documentation on it. Do you have any idea on how to profile in PyV8 without me having to rewrite the Python-to-JS wrapper?

Do you know of any JS-only-framework that uses monkey patching in order to generate a timing profile? It's not a big deal if there is some overhead involved - better than not having a profile at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've found the hint I needed in the book 'Pro Javascript Design Patterns': Use a closure together with `func.apply` to apply instrumentation on functions. Unfortunately, the JS way of decorating functions is not quite as clean as Python's - but hey, it works and I get the information I need to drill down into the code's performance characteristics.

**profile.js**

```
function mod_profiler() {
    var profile_by_function_name = {};
    var total_time = 0;
    var time_counting_for_function = null;

    function get_function_name(func) {
        var result = func.toString();
        result = result.substr('function '.length);
        result = result.substr(0, result.indexOf('('));
        return result;
    }

    function update_profile(function_name, elapsed_time) {
        var profile = profile_by_function_name[function_name];
        if (profile === undefined) {
            profile = {calls:0, elapsed_time:0};
            profile_by_function_name[function_name] = profile;
        }
        profile.calls += 1;
        profile.elapsed_time += elapsed_time;
        if (time_counting_for_function === function_name) {
            total_time += elapsed_time;
        }
    }

    function profile(func) {
        function profiled() {
            var function_name = get_function_name(func);
            if (time_counting_for_function === null) {
                time_counting_for_function = function_name;
            }
            var start_time = new Date().getTime()
            var result = func.apply(undefined, arguments);
            var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
            update_profile(function_name, elapsed_time);
            if (time_counting_for_function === function_name) {
                time_counting_for_function = null;
            }
            return result;
        }
        return profiled;
    }

    function get_formatted_result() {
        function get_whitespace(length) {
            var result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result += " ";
            }
            return result;
        }

        var function_names = Object.keys(profile_by_function_name);
        var function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time = function_names.sort(function (a,b) {
            var elapsed_a = profile_by_function_name[a].elapsed_time;
            var elapsed_b = profile_by_function_name[b].elapsed_time;
            if (elapsed_a < elapsed_b) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (elapsed_a > elapsed_b) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        var max_name_length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time.length; i++) {
            if (function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time[i].length > max_name_length) {
                max_name_length = function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time[i].length;
            }
        }
        var result = "\n" + get_whitespace(max_name_length) + " " + "#calls\telapsed\t% of total\n";
        for (var i = 0; i < function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time.length; i++) {
            if (total_time === 0) {
                break;
            }
            var function_name = function_names_sorted_by_elapsed_time[i];
            var percentage_elapsed = profile_by_function_name[function_name].elapsed_time * 100 / total_time;
            if (percentage_elapsed < 0.3) {
                break;
            }
            result += function_name + ":" + get_whitespace(max_name_length - 1 - function_name.length) + profile_by_function_name[function_name].calls + "\t" + profile_by_function_name[function_name].elapsed_time + "\t" + percentage_elapsed.toFixed(2) + "\n";
        }
        result += "==========\n";
        result += "total time accounted for [ms]: " + total_time;
        return result;
    }

    return {
        profile: profile,
        get_formatted_result: get_formatted_result
    }
}
```

**my_module_1.js**

```
function mod_1(profiler_param) {
    var profiler = profiler_param;

    function my_private_func() {
        return "hello world2";
    }
    if (typeof(profiler) === 'object' && profiler !== null) {
    render_user_menu = profiler.profile(render_user_menu);
} //private functions need the instrumentation to be added manually or else they're not included in the profiling.

    function my_public_func1() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    function my_public_func2(input1, input2) {
        return my_private_func() + input1 + input2;
    }

    //public functions get the instrumentations automatically as long as they're called from outside the module
    var public_function_by_names = {
        my_public_func1: my_public_func1
        my_public_func2: my_public_func2
    }

    var result = {};
    var public_function_names = Object.keys(public_function_by_names);
    for (var i = 0; i < public_function_names.length; i++) {
        var func = public_function_by_names[public_function_names[i]];
        if (typeof(profiler) === 'object' && profiler !== null) {
            result[public_function_names[i]] = profiler.profile(func);
        }
        else {
            result[public_function_names[i]] = func;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**PyV8 side**

```
with X4GEJSContext(extensions=['profile', 'my_module_1']) as ctx:
    if self.enable_profiling == True:
    ctx.eval("var profiler = mod_profiler();")
        ctx.eval("var mod1 = mod_1(profiler);")
        #note: you can pass profiler to as many modules as you want and they get instrumented together.
        logging.info(ctx.eval("mod1.my_public_func_1() + mod1.my_public_func_2('a', 3);"))
        logging.info(ctx.eval("profiler.get_formatted_result();"))
    else:
        ctx.eval("var mod1 = mod_1();") #it still works without the profiler
```

**Output**

```
"hello worldhelloworld2a3"
                                                                                 #calls elapsed % of total
  my_public_func1:                                                                 1    31  50.00
  my_public_func2:                                                                 1    31  50.00
  my_private_func:                                                                 1    31  50.00

  ==========
  total time accounted for [ms]: 62
```